# Importing Two Sets of Data from Same Excel Sheet In MATLab

Tags: excel, matlab

I am working on a small project for a professor at the university who needs data sorted through MATLAB with various other operations done to the data.  I have read in the data with no problem using:

```
filename = 'file.xlsx';
data = xlsread(filename)
```

With this it imports all the data into one big matrix.  From here, within the file itself, there data is divided into 2 main categories, left knee and right knee.

What my issue is is I have tried to separate the data, but have not had any luck.  Since the two sets are NOT divided by equal rows, I can't use a simple array to select the different columns.  The green columns are set one and the gold is set two.  Is there a way that I can look at the second row to see if it's left or right and then put the data into different sets that way?  Or is there a better way to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saw your screenshot ... you've GOT the left or right knee designation right there in the column header.

But xlsread doesn't give the column headers, only the numbers ... or does it?

From [Matlab help for xlsread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbmn):

```
[ndata, text, alldata] = xlsread('myExample.xlsx')
ndata =
     1     2     3
     4     5   NaN
     7     8     9

text = 
    'First'    'Second'    'Third'
    ''         ''          ''     
    ''         ''          'x'    

alldata = 
    'First'    'Second'    'Third'
    [    1]    [     2]    [    3]
    [    4]    [     5]    'x'    
    [    7]    [     8]    [    9]

xlsread returns numeric data in array ndata, text data in cell array text, and unprocessed data in cell array alldata.
```

So, right now you are getting "ndata" but you want to get "text" too.  Set up one more additional output argument for xlsread and you should get it.

```
[data, text, ~] = xlsread(filename); % the ~ just means throw away that third output
```

Then you can use strfind or strcmp on the appropriate row to pull out "Left" or "Right."

Comment: I have tried using the strfind command using:
strLeft = strfind(text, 'Left') 
and now I can see where all the columns with left are.  From here how do I pull out the columns from the data section (the actual numbers)? If it helps I can send you the actual spreadsheet.

Comment: [~,c] = find(strcmp(text,'Left'));
    
    left_data = data(:,c);

Comment: When I do that I receive:

>> [~,c] = find(strcmp(text, 'Left'));
>> left_data = data(:,c);
>> left_data

left_data =

   Empty matrix: 101-by-0

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because strcmp checks the full string, and your strings look like they are called 'Left Knee Angle' rather than 'Left'.  Otherwise, I would recommend using the [debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to step through your code line by line to see where the problem is.  (Good advice for any programming problem, btw!)

Comment: So would the strfind be better to use?  Or just type the whole thing in for 'Left'?  I'm still in college and learning more and more everyday. I got asked to help a prof with this and said it would be a good learning experience...boy was I right haha.

Comment: They are both pretty similar; the outputs are slightly different so you can't just replace [strcmp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) in my example with [strfind](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the **data** is placed in a specific range you can do this for each set of data:

```
filename = 'file.xlsx';
sheet = 1;
xlRange = 'B2:C3';
subsetA = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange)
```

or you can read a column of data:

```
columnB = xlsread(filename,'B:B')
```

otherwise you should separate the data after loading it into **data** array as you did before.

Comment: There can be a different number of trials in each excel sheet, and a random number of 'left' and 'right' sets.  So I am needing a way to separate them either in the matrix or just pick out the right cells.  Is this possible?

Comment: can you provide a simple example of the sheet?"

Comment: Here is a link to it on my photobucket:
http://i1053.photobucket.com/albums/s463/aj_deuerling/excel.jpg
One set is green and the other is gold as you can see in the photo.